TypeScript object property type cast
I have the following object type which may contain sensitive data:
type BalanceInfo {
  currency: string;
  rubAmount: number;
  usdAmount: number;
}

I also have a function which takes an object of this type, masks rubAmount and usdAmount properties, and returns the masked object. I use '*' as the masking character, which requires the properties to be strings. How can I avoid the error Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'. in that case?
Playground

please provide the test case on https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/

What behaviour do you actually want here? You certainly can't claim that the result of the masking is still a BalanceInfo, because e.g. info.rubAmount * 2 would now result in NaN.

Maybe you want something like https://tsplay.dev/N9DgVw, for example - applying the mask function returns something that reflects that those properties are now strings.

@AlexanderNenashev take a look please https://shorturl.at/seJOE

@jonrsharpe I expect my function to allow me to change the properties of an object I received and return that modified object. I don't want to create a new duplicate type that just has a different type for those properties. I don't want to write number | string either

Well then you're going to have a bad time, because now your types are exactly wrong - the result of masking a BalanceInfo, replacing some of its properties with strings whether or not they were originally strings, is not itself a BalanceInfo, whether or not you force it with a type assertion. If you're using TypeScript, use TypeScript.

Please [edit] the question to put the [mre] in there. tsplay is a great supplement but it's not sufficient, especially not in a comment. The code has to be here as plain text in the body of the question, or it risks being closed as needing debugging details.

Since your amount fields can be a masked string number, just add string to their type:
type BalanceInfo = {
  currency: string;
  rubAmount: number | string;
  usdAmount: number | string;
}

But I would add a separate type for the masked strings, that's considered a good design pattern to have only valid types in the props:
type BalanceInfo = {
  currency: string;
  rubAmount: number;
  usdAmount: number;
}

type BalanceInfoMasked = {
  currency: string;
  rubAmount: string;
  usdAmount: string;
}

const maskBalance = () => '*';

const maskBalanceInfo = (balanceInfo: BalanceInfo): BalanceInfoMasked => {
    return {
      currency: balanceInfo.currency,
      rubAmount: maskBalance(),
      usdAmount: maskBalance(),
    }
}


I believe in this instance you'd benefit from that function returning a different type for the masked object, since it's fundamentally different, instead of the params and return sharing the same type. It can be something like this:
interface BalanceInfo {
  currency: string;
  rubAmount: number;
  usdAmount: number;
}

interface MaskedBalanceInfo extends BalanceInfo {
  rubAmount: number | string;
  usdAmount: number | string;
}

like Alexander Nenashev mentioned. That way you have more control on your code on whether the information available is masked or is genuine.
Another solution is, as he mentioned, changing the type itself, but then you'd have to deal with the possibility of rubAmount and usdAmount being strings in cases where you 100% know they are a number, which is annoying. So I'd go for a MaskedBalanceInfo type

Interface 'MaskedBalanceInfo' incorrectly extends interface 'BalanceInfo'. Types of property 'rubAmount' are incompatible.
